# Multiple CSS counters not working as expected

Tags: css

I am trying to create multiple levels of counters in a html table, but this is not working as I expected.
The first counter works ok, but the next counters do not work. Somehow the counters are not incrementing or are reset wrongly?

The code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Counter Demo</title>
    <style>
      table.tasksteps {
          counter-reset: tasksteps;
      }

      td.taskstep {
          counter-reset: risks;
          counter-increment: tasksteps;
      }

      td.risk {
          counter-reset: measures;
          counter-increment: risks;
      }

      td.measure {
          counter-increment: measures;
      }

      td.taskstep:before {
          content: counter(tasksteps) '. ';
      }

      td.risk:before {
          content: counter(tasksteps) '.' counter(risks) '. ';
      }

      td.measure:before {
          content: counter(tasksteps) '.' counter(risks) '.' counter(measures) '. ';
      }

</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="tasksteps">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>TaakStep</td>
          <td>Risk</td>
          <td>Measure</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="taskstep t1">Step 1</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="taskstep t2">Step 2</td>
          <td class="risk">Risk 1</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="t3"></td>
          <td class="risk">Risk 2</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="taskstep t2">Step 3</td>
          <td class="risk">Risk 3</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="taskstep t2">Step 4</td>
          <td class="risk">Risk 4</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="t4"></td>
          <td class="risk">Risk 5</td>
          <td class="measure">Measure 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="t5"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td class="measure">Measure 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="t5"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td class="measure">Measure 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="t5"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td class="measure">Measure 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="t3"></td>
          <td class="risk">Risk 6</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="t4"></td>
          <td class="risk">Risk 7</td>
          <td class="measure">Measure 5</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

This gives output:
[image: Output from above code]

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6VN5R/1/)

Comment: It looks like the way table elements are structured may be interfering with the counter scope, although I am not quite sure how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 problems here:

1. The **direct** parent of the first counted element should contain all the other counted elements. In your case, the first counted element is a `td` in a row, so its parent is a `tr` **but** all the other counted elements have their own parents of `tr` (which are siblings of the parent of the first counted element). So to fix this I think you have to set the class on the `tr` and count it there.
2. The `counter-reset` and `counter-increment` can be overridden, that means if at one `tr`, you need to use `counter-reset` and `counter-increment` for more than 1 counter variable, you need to put them on the same declaration (space-separated) for `counter-reset` and `counter-increment`.

From 2 points above, here is the code it should be:

**HTML**:

```
<table class="tasksteps">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>TaakStep</td>
      <td>Risk</td>
      <td>Measure</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>        
    <tr class="taskstep">
      <td class="taskstep t1">Step 1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="taskstep risk">
      <td class="taskstep t2">Step 2</td>
      <td class="risk">Risk 1</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="risk">
      <td class="t3"></td>
      <td class="risk">Risk 2</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="taskstep risk">
      <td class="taskstep t2">Step 3</td>
      <td class="risk">Risk 3</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="taskstep risk">
      <td class="taskstep t2">Step 4</td>
      <td class="risk">Risk 4</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="risk">
      <td class="t4"></td>
      <td class="risk">Risk 5</td>
      <td class="measure">Measure 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="t5"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="measure">Measure 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="t5"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="measure">Measure 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="t5"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="measure">Measure 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="risk">
      <td class="t3"></td>
      <td class="risk">Risk 6</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="risk">
      <td class="t4"></td>
      <td class="risk">Risk 7</td>
      <td class="measure">Measure 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**:

```
  table.tasksteps {
      counter-reset: tasksteps;
  }      
  tr.taskstep {
      counter-reset: risks;
      counter-increment: tasksteps;
  }    
  tr.risk {          
      counter-reset: measures;
      counter-increment: risks;
  }
  tr.taskstep.risk {
      counter-reset: risks measures;
      counter-increment: tasksteps risks;
  }
  td.measure {
      counter-increment: measures;
  }

  td.taskstep:before {
      content: counter(tasksteps) '. ';
  }

  td.risk:before {
      content: counter(tasksteps) '.' counter(risks) '. ';
  }

  td.measure:before {
      content: counter(tasksteps) '.' counter(risks) '.' counter(measures) '. ';
  }
```

### [Updated Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/6VN5R/5/)

Comment: This is what I meant by the table elements interfering with the counter scope. The solution therefore is to change the structure to accommodate the scope, as is being done here.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect though - counters are separated by whitespace, not commas. The demo is not displaying correctly due to the incorrect syntax.

Comment: @BoltClock maybe I missed about the counters, but the display is correct I think.

Comment: Can't be. The syntax is invalid. If the browser is interpreting the commas "correctly" instead of ignoring them as it should, then it's a bug.

Comment: @BoltClock I updated the answer with space separated, I think it's good now, in fact when the comma was used, only the first one was accepted, all the others were ignored.

Comment: Yeah it looks better now.

Comment: How could I find this out myself? Do you have sources?

Comment: @JasperT I don't think we can find the first point in some reference out there easily. In fact that was derived from experiment and I'm sure it's true. It's like in CSS you cannot jump out of the parent scope of the selected element to traverse forwards after that. For the second point, it's normally that almost CSS properties can be overridden (that means another rule may override one rule with the same property set to different values) and also I've tested both points. They are surely true.

Answer (score 0):

I played a bit, and it seems the issue was resetting all the counters on the same line in the body.

Here's the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6VN5R/2/).

CSS

```
body {
  counter-reset: tasksteps risks measures;
}
table td {
  width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td.taskstep {
  counter-increment: tasksteps;
}
td.risk {
  counter-increment: risks;
}
td.measure {
  counter-increment: measures;
}
td.taskstep:before {
  content: counter(tasksteps) '. ';
}
td.risk:before {
  content: counter(tasksteps) '.' counter(risks) '. ';
}
td.measure:before {
          content: counter(tasksteps) '.' counter(risks) '.' counter(measures) '. ';
      }
```

Comment: All you've basically done here is move all the resets to the same element - there is no difference whether you reset it on the body or the table, either way it messes up the counter styles completely.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is designed to take advantage of the hierarchical nature of HTML, hence the "cascading" style sheets. The element structure of your table is linear and as such defeats the efficiency of the cascade. I understand that there are circumstances when you might not have control over the HTML structure of the document in which case a CSS kluge might be in order. Otherwise, I would suggest restructuring your elements to match the same hierarchy of the layout you're trying to achieve. MUCH simpler and more scalable code.

**HTML:**

```
 <ul>
  <li class='taskstep'>Step 1</li>
  <li class='taskstep'>Step 2
    <ul>
      <li class='risk'>Risk 1</li>
      <li class='risk'>Risk 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='taskstep'>Step 3
    <ul>
      <li class='risk'>Risk 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='taskstep'>Step 4
    <ul>  
      <li class='risk'>Risk 4</li>
      <li class='risk'>Risk 5</li>
        <ul>  
          <li class='measure'>Measure 1</li>
          <li class='measure'>Measure 2</li>
          <li class='measure'>Measure 3</li>
          <li class='measure'>Measure 4</li>
        </ul>
      <li class='risk'>Risk 6</li>
      <li class='risk'>Risk 7</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: foo;
}
li:before{
  counter-increment: foo;
  content: counters(foo,".") ". ";
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4KXuR/)

Comment: Had that code before, but I couldn't get headers above each column in that way.