# CSS counter increment does not work as expected

Tags: html, css

I don't really understand why the counter doesn't increment the h3 elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lqcqzta6/

```
<style>
h1
{
    counter-reset: h2counter;
}


h2:before
{
    content: counter(h2counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0";
    counter-increment: h2counter;
    counter-reset: h3counter;
}

h3:before
{
    content: counter(h2counter) "." counter(h3counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0";
    counter-increment: h3counter;              
}
</style>

<html>
    <body>
        <h1>XXXX</h1>
        <h2>YYYY</h2>
        <h3>ZZZZ</h3>
        <h3>ZZZZ</h3>
        <h3>ZZZZ</h3>
        <h2>YYYY</h2>
        <h3>ZZZZ</h3>
        <h3>ZZZZ</h3>
        <h3>ZZZZ</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

I found an example that explains something similar, but that problem was about elements that didn't have the same direct parent. These have.

[Multiple CSS counters not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980085/multiple-css-counters-not-working-as-expected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you have applied `counter-reset: h3counter` in the wrong place i.e. `h2:before`. You will need to apply `counter-reset: h3counter` to the `<h2>` tag not its `:before`

```css
h1 {
  counter-reset: h2counter;
}

h2 {
  counter-reset: h3counter;
}

h2:before {
  content: counter(h2counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0";
  counter-increment: h2counter;
}

h3:before {
  content: counter(h2counter) "." counter(h3counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0";
  counter-increment: h3counter;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  XXXX
</h1>
<h2>
  YYYY
</h2>
<h3>
  ZZZZZZ
</h3>
<h3>
  ZZZZZZ
</h3>
<h3>
  ZZZZZZ
</h3>
<h2>
  YYYY
</h2>
<h3>
  ZZZZZZ
</h3>
<h3>
  ZZZZZZ
</h3>
<h3>
  ZZZZZZ
</h3>
```

Comment: Why does it matter if it’s reset on the element or its `::before` element?

Answer (score 0):

You can't reset in the pseudo element before for you `h2` instruction.

```css
h1 {
  counter-reset: h2counter;
}

h2 {
  counter-reset: h3counter;
}

h2:before {
  content: counter(h2counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0";
  counter-increment: h2counter;
}

h3:before {
  content: counter(h2counter) "." counter(h3counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0";
  counter-increment: h3counter;              
}
```

```html
<h1>h1 - 1</h1>
<h2>h2 - 1</h2>
<h3>h3 - 1</h3>
<h3>h3 - 2</h3>
<h3>h3 - 3</h3>
<h2>h2 - 2</h2>
<h3>h3 - 1</h3>
<h3>h3 - 2</h3>
<h3>h3 - 3</h3>
```